# Avoid multiple pages

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Is it impossible to generate a PDF from HTML source as one single long paper? Since now if the content exceeds the A4 (for instance) paper height, it moves content to the next page.

Comment: I know it's not about the tool you are currently using, but there's section entitled *Converting an HTML page to a single-page PDF* in the [iText 7 HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml).

Answer (score 0):

I'm 90% sure that you can't do anything preemptive except guesstimate the size of the resulting PDF, which is not reliable.

I would generate the PDF and then use pdftk (or similar tool) to check how many pages were generated. Based on that, you could run wkhtmltopdf with the `--page-height` option set to something higher than an A4 and loop this process until you have the desired one page output.

Tedious, but the only reliable way.